# Analogue of Bargmann's theorem for Super Lie groups

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, supersymmetry, topology

Bargmann's theorem gives the criteria under which a projective representation of a Lie group $G$ can be lifted to a representation of its universal cover. More generally, if this criterion, namely $H^2(Lie G, \mathbb{R}) \neq \{e\}$ is not met, then we can lift the projective representation to a representation of a central extension by $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some $n$ of the original group $G$. My question is: is there a version of this theorem for representations of Super Lie groups? Is there such a notion of lifting a projective representation of a Super Lie Group?

Comment: What kind of statement are you looking for here, exactly? That projective representations are linear representations of central extensions should carry through for supergroups just like for groups (if you don't think so: can you point out where it fails?), and that central extensions are classified by $H^2$ is the *definition* of $H^2$ in some approaches. So what statement *exactly* are you looking for here?

Comment: I don't have a counterexample, but I haven't yet seen a proof of your statement related to supergroups. If you find a reference or a proof, please let me know. I am wondering what kind of definition should H^2 (in group theoretic setting) obtain in the super setting, in order for this to work. Moreover, I am interested in how one would define H^2 for super Lie algebras to obtain a result similar to Bargmann's theorem on vanishing "second super Lie algebra cohomology" to lift the representation.

Comment: To put it clear: I am looking for a concrete statement, which sounds similar to: Let $G$ be a super Lie group. If $H^2(Lie(G),\mathbb{R})=\{e\}$, then every projective representation of $G$ can be lifted to an ordinary representation of $G$. How to define $H^2(Lie(G),\mathbb{R})$ for this to work? How to define Super Lie group cohomology?

Comment: As of to add why it is not clear to me that it should carry over verbatim, it is because in the definition of a representation of a Lie supergroup, the target vector space is a super Hilbert space, not a Hilbert space itself, so you have a grading. How to deal with that precisely?